# complicado srcset

Tags: img, src

Estoy en una formacion de **full stack** recien empezando pero, me va bien lo unico y la unica duda de todos estos dos meses es el **src set**.

El **src** bien pero el **srcset**, no entiendo por que pero de verdad meto las dos fotos de diferente resolucion con su **3x** para hacer que sea foto **responsive** dependiendo del dispositivo pero aun asi nada.

Se carga la foto **mobile** después de cambiar el tamaño de la ventana de **chrome** y **zoom por 200**. Pero después, al hacer la ventana normal a **100** y de escritorio normal no carga la *normal*, sigue la de *mobile*.

Es incomprensible he visto millones de tutos y nada .... he utilizado hasta fotos webp.

Comment: Por favor pon un ejemplo de cómo los tienes hecho

Comment: En cuanto pueda esta tarde en cuanto llegue al espace co-working enseñare pero ya lo consegui dñp ro de una manera extraña me funciona con el w asi 200w no con el 2x o 3x no se por que